# Implementing simple inheritance in Javascript with Selfish

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm attempting to implement some simple inheritance using the Selfish library. Here's a cut-down example:

```
var App = Base.extend({

    options: {
        theme: 'b',
        scriptpath: '',
        exitPrompt: ''
    },

    initialize: function(opts) {
        console.log('App initialize');
        this.options = $.extend({}, this.options, (opts || {}));
    }

});

var SubApp = App.extend({

    intialize: function(opts) {
        console.log('Subapp initialize');
        App.initialize.call(this, opts);    
    }

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Document ready');
    var sub = SubApp.new({
        theme: 'b',
        scriptpath: '../js/'
    });
});
```

The problem being that initialize in SubApp is never called. Curious as to what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are just missing a i in `intialize`

BTW you should call `App.prototype.initializ` as in the readme